# Sagemaker pipeline not getting triggered from S3 event bridge

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, aws-event-bridge

I am using the event bridge rules console to trigger change/upload the new .csv file in the input_data folder in the bucket to trigger Sagemaker pipeline. But the Sagemaker pipeline is not being triggered.

Here is what I did :

1. Created a new folder input_data in the bucket.
2. Uploaded churn.csv
3. When I upload again churn.csv, it should trigger Sagemaker pipeline.

This is my event pattern

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["sagemaker-project-p-jsisqxxxxxx"]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{
        "prefix": "input_data/"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

This is my target
[image]

Can you please help me where I am making the mistake?

Comment: can you check monitoring logs, maybe it tried to execute but failed due to some permission error.

Comment: You should on the event bridge under the properties of s3 bucket. Have you checked that?

Comment: Creating a rule that triggers a SageMaker Pipeline when new data is available on S3 need an extra step. S3 object-level data events are not processed by EventBridge. To do so, it is necessary to configure a CloudTrail trail to capture those object-level S3 events.
See this: https://awstip.com/how-to-automatically-trigger-a-sagemaker-pipeline-using-eventbridge-3b71829a9e5